# Angular 2 Semantic UI Dropdown JS not working

Tags: angular, semantic-ui

I am trying to create a generic drop down control in Angular 2, using Semantic UI. I have the following code:

```
import {ElementRef, Component, OnInit, EventEmitter} from "angular2/core";
import {DropdownValue} from "./dropdown-value";

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
selector: 'my-dropdown',
inputs: ['selectedItem', 'items', 'label'],
outputs: ['selectedItemChange'],
template: `
<div class="field">        
  <label>{{label}}</label>        
    <select class="ui selection dropdown" [ngModel]="selectedItem.value" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
      <!--<option value="" selected>Please Select</option>-->
      <option *ngFor="#item of items" [value]="item.value">{{item.label}}</option>
    </select>        
</div>`
})

export class MyDropdownComponent implements OnInit {

items: DropdownValue[];
selectedItem: DropdownValue;
selectedItemChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
}

ngOnInit(): any {
    this.items.unshift(new DropdownValue('', 'Please Select'));
    this.selectedItem = this.selectedItem || this.items[0];
    //jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('select').dropdown();
}

onChange(newValue) {
    let selectedItem = this.items.find(item => item.value == newValue);
    this.selectedItemChange.emit(selectedItem);
}

}
```

This actually works just fine as it is (without Semantic UI JS styling), the issue is, as soon as I uncomment the line `//jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('select').dropdown();` the 'Please Select' is no longer visible and it does not show the initial selection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Günter said, you should call `jQuery().dropdown()` in ngAfterViewInit().

`dropdown()` resets the selected value. so you have to reselect the desired value after `dropdown()`:

```js
ngAfterViewInit(){
  jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('select').dropdown({allowTab:false});
  jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('select').dropdown("set selected",this.selectedItem.value);
}
```

See [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/I4Vlmqmr4lMJVxyK2W6z?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
setTimeout(() => 
  jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('select').dropdown();
}, 1);
```

to give Angular some air to breath - update the view to show `this.items.unshift`

or use `ngAfterViewInit()`. This way it should work without `setTimeout()`

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('select').dropdown();
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate: update the view to show `this.items.unshift`?

Comment: When you add/remove items from an array you (or otherwise change a value bound from the view `*ngFor="#item of items"`), the view is only updated after the next change detection cycle. Change detection can't run between synchronous executed lines of code. Therefore we reschedule the `jQuery` call to allow Angular to do change detection and update the HTML and only then `jQuery()` will find the element there.

Comment: If I put the JQuery in a timeout as you suggested, it loses it initial selection. I am setting initial selection on ngOnInit as follows: `this.selectedItems = this.items[1];`

Comment: Can you create a Plunker? I don't use jQuery myself and it's hard to reason about what exactly might be going on from looking at the static code.

Comment: I have created a Plunker: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/7e20MEzsC3ekwHeLoB6e?p=preview). Please notice that the selected item is not displayed, it only does when you comment out the line: `jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('select').dropdown();`

Comment: This seems to be a jQuery dropdown feature. If you change `this.items.unshift(new DropdownValue('', 'Please Select'));` to `this.items.unshift(new DropdownValue('3', 'Please Select'));` (set a value) then it is shown. jQuery dropdown seems to hide items without a value. If you check the DOM it is there either way.

Comment: If I set the 'value' of the DropDownValue, it no longer has the item selected, instead it says, 'Please Select'. I need it to keep the selected item (like when the JQuery is commented out).

Comment: That may be, but I don't think this is an Angular issue. I can't help you with jQuery or Semantic-UI

Comment: @EnlitenedZA did you find a solution for this problem? I noticed in [your plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7e20MEzsC3ekwHeLoB6e?p=preview) that when you introduce the `jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('select').dropdown();` not only does the dropdown lose it's initial value - it also does not register the value change. I am a bit lost on how to avoid these problems with Semantic UI.

Comment: Why do you think the setTimeout necessary?  Is it an Angular bug initialising values too soon? It is a shame Directives don't have something like onAfterViewInit method.

Comment: See @schnoedel 's answer